# php/ajax : json data.message returns undefiend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i made a form in a php file and i send request to another php file(test2.php) using ajax
when i get data back to ajax and i want to print in id="txtHint2" ( paragraph tag ) it shows undefiend
what is the problem?

this is my  **ajax file** code:

```
function add_product_category_main_form(){

var formdata={
'name':     $('input[name=product_group_name]').val()
};

    $.ajax({
        url:        "http://localhost/mysite/admin/php/test2.php",
        type:       "post",
        data:       formdata,
        datatype:   "json"

    })

    .done(function(data){

            document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML=data;
            document.getElementById('txtHint2').innerHTML=data.message;
        if( !data.success ){
            window.alert(data.errors.name);
        }
        else{           
            alert(data.message);
        }

    })

    .fail(function(data){
        alert("ajax failed");
    });

}
```

and this is **test2.php**:

```
<?php
include('../includes/db_connection.php');
$errors = array();
$data = array();

if( empty($_POST['name']) )
$errors['name'] = "Name is Required!";

if( !empty($errors) ){
$data['success'] = false;
$data['errors'] = $errors;

}else{

$name=$_POST['name'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_group_main(product_group_main_name) VALUE ('$name')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = "successfully inserted";
$data['name'] = $name;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

all other parts, such as insert into database works fine

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText); console.log(data.message)`

Comment: and how to use this code? i'm new in php

Comment: try this in ur url:yourIpAddress:port/mysite/admin/php/test2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive! `datatype` should be `dataType`.